# How to find my javascript function in Jint in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I wrote code below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new Engine();
        var file = File.ReadAllText(@"...\Desktop\beautify.js");
        var final = file + Environment.NewLine + "(function () {return js_beautify('var a = 2;');})();";
        var exec = engine.Execute(final);
        var r = exec.GetCompletionValue().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.Read();

    }
```

but the Jint show error

```
Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException: 'js_beautify is not defined'
```

Can anyone help me how to register external js libraries like beautify.js and then call functions of them in Jint ?

Comment: can you show me the bookstore beautify.js

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.14/beautify.js

Comment: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: Can you try `var final = file + Environment.NewLine + "(function () {return global.js_beautify('var a = 2;');})();";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
 var engine = new Engine().Execute("var global = {};").Execute(content);
 var js_beautify = engine.Execute("global.js_beautify").GetCompletionValue();
 var result = engine.Invoke(js_beautify, "var a = 2;").AsString();
```